# Python - Sort a list of dics by value of dict`s dict value

Tags: python, list, sorting, quicksort

I have a list that looks like this:

```
persons = [{'id': 11, 'passport': {'id': 11, 'birth_info':{'date': 10/10/2016...}}},{'id': 22, 'passport': {'id': 22, 'birth_info':{'date': 11/11/2016...}}}]
```

I need to sort the list of persons by their sub key of sub key - their birth_info date.

How should I do it ?
Thanks

Comment: That's a `dict` you got there inside the `list` of `persons`.

Comment: That right my friend

Comment: You should fix your sample data: those date strings need to be quoted to make that list legal Python (and legal JSON).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `sorted()` provides the `key` argument. One can define a callable which returns the key to compare the items:

```
sorted(persons, key=lambda x: x['passport']['birth_info']['date'])
```

The argument x is an item of the given list of persons.

If the dates are strings you could use the `datetime` module:

```
sorted(persons, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['passport']['birth_info']['date'], '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: sort or sorted?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime


print(sorted(persons, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['passport']['birth_info']['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"))) #reverse=True for descending order.
```