# how do i sort a dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a dict inside a list

```
alldata = [{'_id': 657974997549056030, 'experience': 10, 'level': 1, 'last_lvl_box': 16, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 563690668808208423, 'experience': 9080, 'level': 9, 'last_lvl_box': 3430, 'complete_box': 2510}, {'_id': 560529834325966858, 'experience': 5596, 'level': 8, 'last_lvl_box': 2465, 'complete_box': 1500}, {'_id': 589125036053495826, 'experience': 5475, 'level': 8, 'last_lvl_box': 2456, 'complete_box': 1370}, {'_id': 517371726720532511, 'experience': 81, 'level': 3, 'last_lvl_box': 175, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 531858459512012811, 'experience': 750, 'level': 5, 'last_lvl_box': 646, 'complete_box': 100}, {'_id': 159985870458322944, 'experience': 390, 'level': 4, 'last_lvl_box': 365, 'complete_box': 130}, {'_id': 734039231810502699, 'experience': 470, 'level': 4, 'last_lvl_box': 365, 'complete_box': 210}, {'_id': 376364173275430913, 'experience': 280, 'level': 4, 'last_lvl_box': 365, 'complete_box': 20}, {'_id': 155149108183695360, 'experience': 120, 'level': 3, 'last_lvl_box': 166, 'complete_box': 30}, {'_id': 414925323197612032, 'experience': 0, 'level': 1, 'last_lvl_box': 16, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 235088799074484224, 'experience': 200, 'level': 3, 'last_lvl_box': 156, 'complete_box': 100}, {'_id': 442033210420101130, 'experience': 560, 'level': 4, 'last_lvl_box': 365, 'complete_box': 300}, {'_id': 615594944568229931, 'experience': 170, 'level': 3, 'last_lvl_box': 166, 'complete_box': 80}, {'_id': 476676359108952064, 'experience': 0, 'level': 1, 'last_lvl_box': 16, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 234395307759108106, 'experience': 640, 'level': 5, 'last_lvl_box': 666, 'complete_box': 10}, {'_id': 448061528826970113, 'experience': 20, 'level': 2, 'last_lvl_box': 61, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 566605346143993856, 'experience': 10, 'level': 1, 'last_lvl_box': 16, 'complete_box': 10}, {'_id': 458276816071950337, 'experience': 90, 'level': 3, 'last_lvl_box': 166, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 330416853971107840, 'experience': 0, 'level': 1, 'last_lvl_box': 16, 'complete_box': 0}, {'_id': 620689014910877719, 'experience': 10, 'level': 1, 'last_lvl_box': 16, 'complete_box': 10}, {'_id': 818403210200612865, 'experience': 160, 'level': 3, 'last_lvl_box': 166, 'complete_box': 70}, {'_id': 580790817262796811, 'experience': 70, 'level': 2, 'last_lvl_box': 61, 'complete_box': 50}]
```

how can I sort this dictionary from the highest 'level' to the lowest 'level'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39804375/476?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a `dict` because it's an orderless data structure - but you're not trying to. Instead, you're sorting a *list of* dicts (this is an important distinction to make). You can use the built-in `sorted` method for that, with a custom sorting key:

```
alldata = sorted(alldata, key=lambda dct: dct['level'], reverse=True)
```

or you can call the `.sort()` method on the list to sort it in-place, using essentially the same arguments:

```
alldata.sort(key=lambda dct: dct['level'], reverse=True)
```

I give `reverse=True` because, by default, the sort puts the smallest `key` first and the largest `key` last, which is the opposite of what we want.

---

If you wanted to go further and, say, break ties in 'level' by the amount of experience, then you can return a tuple from the lambda, with elements ordered by sort priority:

```
key=lambda dct: (dct['level'], dct['experience'])
```